# How to read out the loss function in YOLO algorithm?

Tags: optimization, machine-learning

How do I read out the [loss function](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/12011058/40285033-0ea541c8-5c4c-11e8-9f43-ca9ea3ad5388.png) used in YOLO?
I somehow need it for a class that I'm attending.

EDIT

Got an [answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmachinelearning/comments/9edk40/how_to_read_out_the_loss_function_used_in_yolo/e5obs51) in Reddit!

Comment: What do you mean by "Read out"? Do you just mean how to understand it?

Comment: @user3658307 Sorry about that, what I was trying to say was how do I read it out loud.

Comment: Thank you for the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of an unexpected question, but I guess I would read it out by describing one term at a time. (Hopefully you meant a high-level description, not literally a phonetic sequence.) I'd say something like this when "reading it out":

- Overall, we want to perform simultaneous object detection and classification. The indicator functions $(\unicode{x1D7D9}_{ij}^{ \text{obj} })$ denote when the $j$th box in cell $i$ (i.e. the $j$th prediction has maximal confidence). Similarly the indicator $(\unicode{x1D7D9}_{i}^{ \text{obj} })$ denotes whether there is an object in cell $i$.
  Hatted quantities (e.g. $\widehat{x}$, $\widehat{C}$, $\widehat{p}_i$) are predictions of their unhatted counterparts.
  The sums over $i$ are over the gridded cells of the image, while the sums over $j$ iterate over the bounding box predictors (per cell).
- The first term checks that the predicted object box centers are close to the real ones, based on the squared distance between the centers.
- The second term checks that the sizes (width $w$ and height $h$) of the predicted and true boxes are close to each other, to maximize overlap between them.
- The third and fourth term measures the existence confidence (or *objectness*), i.e. $C_i$ gives the probability of an object being in cell $i$ at all, so the loss want the confidence of our learner to match whether or not an object is actually present.
- The fifth term is the classification loss, so that the network correctly categorizes each object *if* an object exists there.

Might be helpful to look at other Yolo questions: 
[[1]](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/353607/on-yolo-and-its-loss-function/355013#355013), 
[[2]](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/276204/how-to-calculate-the-class-probability-of-a-grid-cell-in-yolo-object-detection-a), 
[[3]](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/332907/yolo-loss-function-width-and-height-component-explanation?noredirect=1&lq=1), 
[[4]](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/333968/understanding-the-yolo-algorithm/355018#355018), 
[[5]](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/287486/yolo-loss-function-explanation/287497),
[[6]](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/5527/understanding-the-loss-function-of-you-only-look-onceyolo-network).